# Как сделать функции записи и чтения файла?

Tags: python, файлы, функции, if

Пользователю высвечивается сообщение, где указано что 1 - запись, 2 чтение. При запуске кода он сразу заканчивается, как исправить и в чем ошибка?

```
def write():
    file = open("test.txt", "a")
    file.write(input())
    file.close()


def read():
    file = open("test.txt", "r")
    print(file.read())
    file.close()


answer = input("Здравствуйте! Что желаете сделать? \n1 - записать в текстовый документ, 2 - прочитать")
if answer == 1:
    write()
elif answer == 2:
    read()
```

Comment: `input()` возвращает строку. Либо сравнивайте, например, `answer == "1"`, либо используйте `answer = int(input())`

Answer (score 0):

```
def write_or_read(choice):
    if not choice.isdigit() or choice not in ['1', '2']:
        print("Введено не верное значение!")
    if choice == '1':
        with open("test.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(input("Введите текст: "))
    if choice == '2':
        with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
            print(file.read())


answer = input("Здравствуйте! Что желаете сделать? \n1 - записать в текстовый  документ\n2 - прочитать\n| ")
write_or_read(choice=answer)
```